# Visual Studio Code Shortcut Run Command in Terminal

Tags: visual-studio-code

How do I have to modify this shortcut setting from VS Code `keybindings.json`, that it runs a command in the current terminal?

This is what I have:

```
[
  { "key": "ctrl+shift+r", "command": "terminal.integrated", "args" : "ionic serve" }
]
```

Comment: I know how to do that with a task that you set a keybinding to.  Let me know if you want to see it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to `File > Preferences > Keyboard Shortcuts` menu.

And in top corner of right side click on `Open Keyboard Shortcuts (JSON)` icon.

Will open `keybinfings.json` file that is a JSON file.

Place your key bindings in this file to override the defaults.

For example put this:

```
[{
    "key": "ctrl+shift+r",
    "command": "workbench.action.terminal.sendSequence",
    "args": { "text": "python '${file}'\u000D" }
}]
```

Now defined new action for `ctrl+shift+r` and will run `python '${file}'` command in here.